# See jupyter notebook diffs between local and remote branch

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for a way to use nbdiff (https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see diffs of notebook between my local version of a notebook and a remote one.
This looks rather straightforward, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I tried

```
nbdiff file.ipynb origin/<branch_name>/file.ipynb
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to see the diffs in the command line, you can do the following after `pip install nbdime`:

```sh
nbdime config-git --enable --global # This will enable git to render diffs for notebooks based on the nbdime logic
git diff notebook.ipynb # no need to specify the "second" file, as in the example
```

This will by default show the diff (in the terminal) of the notebook/file you have locally vs the notebook/file you have in the remote.

If you want to be extra specific about *which* branch to compare to, you can specify:

```sh
git diff origin/<branch_name> -- notebook.ipynb
```

And this is how the diff would render:

[image]

Finally, if you want the web UI, you can run

```
nbdiff-web
```

and it will automatically open the difftool in a browser, showing you the differences between the local and the remote.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! Though doing your trick, i see the diffs with all the json, "celltype", "metadata", etc. Any way to have diffs like nbdiff shows usually, that is, json stripped out ?

Comment: @Tom so it looks like git is not picking up the `nbdime` diff driver. According to the docs, there are two ways to do it: one is the one above (`nbdime config-git --enable --global` this is global) and the other one is manually by editing the `.gitconfig` file. Can you see if you have the following two lines in your `.gitconfig` file? 
`[diff "jupyternotebook"]
 command = git-nbdiffdriver diff`

See the details on manual registration here: https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vcs.html#manual-registration

Comment: Thx again ! Apparently, there needs also to be a `*.ipynb diff=jupyternotebook` configuration to put in .gitattributes, however, I already have `*.ipynb diff=ipynb` due to nbstripout. Can I use both of them ? On two seperate lines or with a coma ?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue. In my case, I have only this one line in `gitattributes`: `*.ipynb filter=nbstripout`. This should, per the installation instructions, only show up in that file or in `.git/info/attributes` (as described here: https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout#configuration-files). After enabling `nbstripout` with `nbstripout --install --global` and `nbdime` with `nbdime config-git --enable --global`, I see the filtered output when running `nbdiff notebook.ipynb`. Does that work for you?